# Why do I get an undefined method `xpath' for #?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have the following XML structure:

```xml
<agencies>
  <city>
    <name>New York</name>
    <address>Street A, 101</address>
    <phone>111-222-333</phone>
  </city>
  <city>
    <name>Chicago</name>
    <address>Street B, 201</address>
    <phone>111-222-333</phone>
  </city>
</agencies>
```

and I'm trying to create a Ruby class to work with it.

I created the class file:

```
require 'nokogiri'

class Agency

  def initialize(arg)
    @file = arg.gsub(/-/,'_')
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("db/agencies/#{@file}.xml"))
  end

  def find_offices
    @doc.xpath('//agencies/city').map do |i|
      { 'name' => xpath('name') }
    end
    #@entries = @doc.xpath('//agencies/city').map do |i|
    #  { 'name' => xpath('name').inner_text, 'address' => xpath('address').inner_text, 'phone' => xpath('phone').inner_text }
    #end
  end
end
```

For my controller I have:

```
class AgenciesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @prefectures = Prefecture.all
  end

  def list
    @prefecture = Agency.new(params[:prefecture_name])
    @offices = @prefecture.find_offices
  end
end
```

The `list` method returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AgenciesController#list

undefined method `xpath' for #<Agency:0x9e7f280>
Rails.root: /home/kleber/projects/rails_apps/job_board2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/agency.rb:13:in `block in find_offices'
app/models/agency.rb:12:in `map'
app/models/agency.rb:12:in `find_offices'
app/controllers/agencies_controller.rb:9:in `list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section looks funny:

```
def find_offices
    @doc.xpath('//agencies/city').map do |i|
      { 'name' => xpath('name') }
    end
```

You create a local variable `i` for each element returned by the `xpath()` query but do not use it. You're calling `xpath('name')`, but I don't see a definition of `xpath()` on the class (or in global scope) that could be called.

Did you mean to write something more like this? (untested) :

```
      { 'name' => i.xpath('name') }
```